# regex: between square brackets exists one string and not exists another

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

My regex question is,

Between square brackets, the text begins with the string

```
'Started'
```

and after it, but between the brackets not exists string

```
'Continue'
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to fit your clarified question.*

This should work, if I understood your question correctly.

```
\[(?![^][]*\bContinue\b)Started[^][]*\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CvyWUj/3)

Explanation:

- Square brackets at the beginning and the end, but none inside by using `[^][]*` instead of `.*`.
- `(?![^][]*\bContinue\b)` makes sure there is no isolated "Continue" within the brackets. I put it where it is when it wasn't clear in your question that "Started" had to be at the beginning - you could move it after "Started" and get the same results.
- `Started[^][]*` matches anything between the square braces, as long as it starts with "Started". If you wanted "Started" *anywhere* inside the square braces, use `[^][]*Started[^][]*` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm so sorry forget one another rule if the word Continue followed by another word immediately it should we exclude, for example, we not need to match those cases where the ContinueBrick, or ContinueMortar also exists.

Comment: No worries, a simple `\b` before and after `Continue` will handle that. Editing my answer.

Comment: If Started is also meant to be a stand-alone word only, add `\b` after it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might be close to what you might want:

```
(?=^\[\bStarted\b(?!.*\bContinue\b).*\]).*
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IfU8Hr/1/)

Comment: It's probably better to use something like `(?![^]]*` for the negative lookahead instead of `(?!.*` to avoid rejecting something like `[Started] Continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a quicker way to do it is this:

`\[Started(?:[^\]]*?\bContinue\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^\]]*\])`

https://regex101.com/r/ZCmv1Y/1

Expanded

```
 \[Started
 (?:
      [^\]]*? \b Continue \b (*SKIP) (*FAIL) 
   |  
      [^\]]* 
      \]
 )
```

A benchmark

```
Regex1:   \[Started(?:[^\]]*?\bContinue\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^\]]*\])
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.93 s,   926.22 ms,   926218 µs
Matches per sec:   161,948


Regex2:   \[(?![^][]*?\bContinue\b)Started[^][]*\]
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    1.21 s,   1212.55 ms,   1212546 µs
Matches per sec:   123,706
```